# Publishing to GeoServer from QGIS?

Tags: qgis, geoserver-explorer

I am trying to publish map layers to GeoServer from QGIS.

I have added the GeoServer Explorer plugin, but it does not seem to connect to our GeoServer successfully. I am able to add it as a Catalog, but with errors, and then none of the current layers or publish options are shown in the plugin tree.

[image]

I also tried uploading through the Processing Toolbox GeoServer options added there with the plugin, but those methods also fail with errors.

Most of the errors seem to have to do with SSL certificates.

Here are the errors I get when adding a Catalog for our server to the GeoServer Explorer plugin:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'title' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Daniel Turet/.qgis2/python/plugins\geoserverexplorer\gui\explorer.py", line 101, in run
    command(*params)
  File "C:/Users/Daniel Turet/.qgis2/python/plugins\geoserverexplorer\gui\gsexploreritems.py", line 551, in populate
    raise e
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'title'
```

```
An error has occurred while executing Python code: 
TypeError: sslErrors() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given) 
TypeError: sslErrors() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
Python version: 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 2.18.14 Las Palmas, c11191e133 
Python Path:
C:/PROGRA~1/BOUNDL~1/Desktop/1.1/osgeo4w/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing
C:\Users\Daniel Turet\.qgis2\python\plugins\geoserverexplorer\ext-libs\httplib2-0.8-py2.7.egg
C:\Users\Daniel Turet\.qgis2\python\plugins\geoserverexplorer\ext-libs\python_dateutil-2.2-py2.7.egg
C:\Users\Daniel Turet\.qgis2\python\plugins\geoserverexplorer\ext-libs\six-1.10.0-py2.7.egg
C:\Users\Daniel Turet\.qgis2\python\plugins\geoserverexplorer\ext-libs\requests-2.5.0-py2.7.egg
C:\Users\Daniel Turet\.qgis2\python\plugins\geoserverexplorer\ext-libs\gsconfig-1.0.6-py2.7.egg
C:\Users\Daniel Turet\.qgis2\python\plugins\geoserverexplorer\ext-libs\gisdata-0.5.4-py2.7.egg
C:\Users\Daniel Turet\.qgis2\python\plugins\geoserverexplorer\ext-libs\gsimporter-1.0.0-py2.7.egg
C:/PROGRA~1/BOUNDL~1/Desktop/1.1/osgeo4w/apps/qgis/./python
C:/Users/Daniel Turet/.qgis2/python
C:/Users/Daniel Turet/.qgis2/python/plugins
C:/PROGRA~1/BOUNDL~1/Desktop/1.1/osgeo4w/apps/qgis/./python/plugins
C:\PROGRA~1\BOUNDL~1\Desktop\1.1\osgeo4w\bin\python27.zip
C:\PROGRA~1\BOUNDL~1\Desktop\1.1\osgeo4w\apps\Python27\DLLs
C:\PROGRA~1\BOUNDL~1\Desktop\1.1\osgeo4w\apps\Python27\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\BOUNDL~1\Desktop\1.1\osgeo4w\apps\Python27\lib\plat-win
C:\PROGRA~1\BOUNDL~1\Desktop\1.1\osgeo4w\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk
C:\PROGRA~1\BOUNDL~1\Desktop\1.1\osgeo4w\bin
C:\PROGRA~1\BOUNDL~1\Desktop\1.1\osgeo4w\apps\Python27
C:\PROGRA~1\BOUNDL~1\Desktop\1.1\osgeo4w\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages
C:\PROGRA~1\BOUNDL~1\Desktop\1.1\osgeo4w\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\BOUNDL~1\Desktop\1.1\osgeo4w\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\markupsafe-0.23-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\BOUNDL~1\Desktop\1.1\osgeo4w\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\PROGRA~1\BOUNDL~1\Desktop\1.1\osgeo4w\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\BOUNDL~1\Desktop\1.1\osgeo4w\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:\PROGRA~1\BOUNDL~1\Desktop\1.1\osgeo4w\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\BOUNDL~1\Desktop\1.1\osgeo4w\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode
C:\PROGRA~1\BOUNDL~1\Desktop\1.1\osgeo4w\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd-0.9.2-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\BOUNDL~1\Desktop\1.1\osgeo4w\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt-0.7.5-py2.7.egg
C:/Users/Daniel Turet/.qgis2//python
C:\Users\Daniel Turet\.qgis2\python\plugins\geoserverexplorer\ext-libs
C:\PROGRA~1\BOUNDL~1\Desktop\1.1\osgeo4w\apps\qgis\python\plugins\boundlessconnect\extlibs
C:\PROGRA~1\BOUNDL~1\Desktop\1.1\osgeo4w\apps\qgis\python\plugins\boundlessconnect\extlibs\future-0.16.0-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\BOUNDL~1\Desktop\1.1\osgeo4w\apps\qgis\python\plugins\boundlessconnect\extlibs\qgiscommons-2.0.5-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\BOUNDL~1\Desktop\1.1\osgeo4w\apps\qgis\python\plugins\reportingtool\extlibs
C:/Users/Daniel Turet/Documents/QGIS
```

Is there any other way to publish to GeoServer?

Answer (score 3):

What we do to solve this problem is to publish data through geoserver (in our case, PostGIS data, though any other data source would be useful).

That data was visualized through QGIS using the standard (though mostly simply) symbology properties at the layer level.

We then export the QGIS symbology as SLD files.

The Geoserver services, in our case WMS services, can have the SLD applied from QGIS, which then results in a Geoserver style that looks exactly like it did in QGIS.

Comment: Thank you for answering. How do you publish through GeoServer?

We have Data Stores set up for various SQL data tables that we can publish map layers from, but in this case I am needing to add a new raster layer to our server. I can't seem to find a way to get it on the server. The GeoServer Explorer plugin for QGIS seems to be what I would need, but it won't connect successfully to our server.

Comment: @DanielTuret we just use the Geoserver web interface to publish layers from data stores... I haven't done anything with rasters, though there are several tutorials and sites that show this (http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/cookbook/rasters.html, https://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/pretty_maps/styling_raster.html). We use Geoserver quite a bit, but using not using the QGIS Geoserver plugin at all...

Comment: Thanks. Yes I have looked at those links. My problem is getting the layer to the server though.

Comment: @DanielTuret Hmm... if the SSL certificate is the issue here hopefully someone can lend a hand!